# Pipe communication (parent -> child -> parent)

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I'm having the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    int pfd[2]; // pipe
    int pfd2[2]; // pipe2
    pid_t pid; // child

    if (pipe(pfd) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (pipe(pfd2) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // child process
    if (pid == 0) { 
        close(pfd[1]);
        int v[100] = {0};
        int k = 0;

        int r;
        char buf[128];

        while ((r = read(pfd[0], buf, sizeof(buf)))) {
            buf[r] = '\0';
            // some processing here vor the 'v' variable
        }

        close(pfd[0]); // close the reading end 1st pipe

        dup2(pfd2[1], 1); // redirect
        close(pfd2[1]);
        execlp("bash", "bash", "script.sh", v, NULL);
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        // parent code
        close(pfd2[1]);
        dup2(pfd2[0], 0);

        char buf[16];
        int r = 0;

        while ((r = read(pfd2[0], buf, sizeof(buf)))) {
            buf[r] = '\0';
            // read here from second pipe
        }

        close(pfd2[0]); // close reading end from 2pnd pipe

        close(pfd[0]); // close reading end from 1st pipe
        dup2(pfd[1], 1); // redirect

        execlp("cat", "cat", argv[1], NULL); // exec 'cat' on the given arg
        exit(-1);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

That respect the following flow: the parent process executes the 'cat' command on the given arg file, then pass it to the child -> the child does some processing and then stores values in the 'v' variable -> then executes the 'script.sh' script with the values taken from the 'v' variable and then passes the output to the parent which will print to stdout the output based on the result from the child.

I'm unsure where should the code for the 2nd pipe reading should go, I'm pretty sure that's the problem right now.

Can anyone take a look at it and point where the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: In the code shown both parent and child appear to block waiting to read from each other without having ever written anything (I think).  Try 'littering' your code with a few `fprintf(stderr, ...` calls to track the progress of parent and child.

Comment: If I just remove the lines before the dup and close calls for the first pipe (pfd), then I get the 'cat' output in the child process. That's where the writing is done from the parent to the child.